# Theoretically speaking what are the limits for super-capacitors in terms of their storage capability?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, renewable-energy

According to wikipedia, commercially available super-capacitors in 2010 can store 30Wh/kg, with 85Wh/kg achieved in a lab in 2011.

Have any theoretical calculations been done to show what can be achieved as an upper limit to super-capacitors?

Comment: I can't see reasons for such limit, can you?

Comment: Unfortunately this is the kind of physics I'd have been a dab hand at school. I doubt (correction, I know) I can't work out the storage capacity of a simple capacitor. If there are no theoretical limits, what are the main limiting factors from a practical point of view?

Comment: From practical point of view in my opinion is how good the insulator between the plates of the capacitor, and I think (just my assumption) that nanotechnologies plays an important rule in making such new materials.

Comment: Nanotechnologies were on my mind when I was asking this question. Insulator=dielectric, right?

Comment: Almost; dielectric are kind of Insulators, please check Wikipedia.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_electron_emission refers to a kind of breakdown that causes electrons to move without a substrate, This presumably puts upper limits on the electric field strength for given materials, and charge density has an upper limit that clearly varies with mass (since capacitors have no net charge and the charge carriers have mass, the maximum charge separation is #e+#P).

Comment: @zackkenyon: Thks for your interesting comment; I'd forgotten that I'd asked this question!

Comment: it's a pretty interesting question! I'm surprised it didn't receive much attention. I don't think my answer is very good, but I think it's a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Working on this problem myself.  Limiting factor is specific surface area (dissociated ion attachment sites) and breakdown of the dielectric (general capacitors use dielectric that have high voltage breakdown levels, supercapacitors have low voltage breakdown levels).  As far as the surface area limitation, supercapacitors use ion chemical potential, the more ions that it has surface area for, the more potential energy it can store on each electrode.

Inputs to calculation:
-total surface area of electrode
-average surface area taken up by each dissociated ion (changes depending on the ion)
-charge of the ion
(assuming there are inexhaustible numbers of ions in electrolyte)

Output:
-divide total surface area by average surface area taken up by each ion. This gives number of attachment sites, multiply by charge of the ion.  This should give specific energy for a given ionic solution (electrolyte).

As far as specific power, I'm guessing it depends on 1. electric potential between electrodes 2. distance between electrodes 3. pore size of separator (and/or electrode porous coating pore size)

Source - an educated guess

Comment: What do you mean a "guess"?  Would help if you could substantiate your answer.

Comment: Do you have any papers you could recommend on the subject?